# Solr location facet search

Tags: solr, location, facet

I'm using solr to do faceted search. 
I'm populated the data in Solr and a typical document looks like:

```
<doc>
<str name="id">1</str>
<date name="last_modified">2012-06-03T07:23:11.215Z</date>
<str name="location">22.60325666,114.1371245</str>
<int name="media_type">0</int>
</doc>
```

When I run a query: 
    {!geofilt pt=37.3320927,-121.90056663 d=100 sfield=location d=5}
I get 2 documents back. Similarly, when I run:
    {!geofilt pt=37.3320927,-121.90056663 d=100 sfield=location d=50}
I get 6 documents back.

But when I run the query:

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/select?sfield=location&pt=37.3320927,-121.90056663&facet.query={!geofilt%20d=10%20key=d10}&facet.query={!geofilt%20d=20%20key=d20}&facet.query={!geofilt%20d=50%20key=d50}&wt=xml&facet=true
```

I get a response:

Similarly for:

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/select?sfield=location&pt=37.3320927,-121.90056663&facet.query={!geofilt%20d=10%20key=d10}&facet.query={!geofilt%20d=20%20key=d20}&facet.query={!geofilt%20d=50%20key=d50}&wt=xml&facet=true
```

I get a response:

Is there anything that I'm doing incorrectly?

Comment: Even though I have media_type defined as, I still can't even run a faceted search on it by doing:    http://localhost:8983/solr/select?q=*.*&rows=0&facet=true&facet.query=media_type:1&facet.query=media_type:2

Answer (score 0):

I got things to work by using the query:

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/select?q=*:*&sfield=location&pt=37.3320927,-121.90056663&facet.query={!frange l=0 u=5}geodist()&facet.query={!frange l=5.001 u=20.0}geodist()& &facet.query={!frange l=20.001 u=100}geodist()&facet.pivot=media_type&wt=xml&facet=true&rows=0
```

The next problems is how do I added another facet to the query? 
Specifically, in this case I'd like to break up the results using media_type.

Comment: I believe Solr supports multiple `fq=` query parameters, so you just add another one to the URL.